# How to animate text with css based on event listener scroll

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js

I want to make a text animation like this website: https://www.viraly.com.br/
They have 3 keyframes for two types of animation Left to Right and Right to Left
RTL start with 164vh
LTR start with -200vh

When those texts are visible the animation starts base on scroll

You can check the final result here: https://hartech.vercel.app/
But I want the same text animation as this website https://www.viraly.com.br/

Can someone provide me some tutorial or help me with the code to achieve that?

This is what I  have tried on NextJs component:

```
export function HartechAnimated() {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {

    const animateElementRTL = document.querySelectorAll('.animateRTL');
    const animateElementLTR = document.querySelectorAll('.animateLTR');

    function isScrolledIntoView(elementsToBeAnimated) {
      elementsToBeAnimated.forEach((element) => {
        const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
        const elemTop = rect.top;
        const elemBottom = rect.bottom;

        // Only completely visible elements return true:
        const isVisible = (elemTop >= 0) && (elemBottom <= window.innerHeight);

        if (isVisible && element.classList.contains('animateRTL')) {
          element.classList.add('resetXRTL')
        } else {
          element.classList.remove('resetXRTL')
        }

        if (isVisible && element.classList.contains('animateLTR')) {
          element.classList.add('resetXLTR')
        } else {
          element.classList.remove('resetXLTR')
        }
      });
    }

    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {

      isScrolledIntoView(animateElementRTL);
      isScrolledIntoView(animateElementLTR);

    }, false);
  }

  return (
    <div className="font-britanica-black-expanded overflow-hidden text-6xl text-white py-20 md:text-black md:text-9xl md:py-36">
      <b className="block animateLTR" id="teste">HARTECH REPARO</b>
      <b className="block hartech-stroke animateRTL">DE PLACAS DE VÍDEO</b>
      <b className="block animateLTR">HARTECH REPARO</b>
    </div >
  );
}
```

CSS

```
.animateRTL {
  transition: transform 2.2s ease-in-out;
  transform: translateX(164vh);
}

.animateLTR {
  transition: transform 2s ease-in-out;
  transform: translateX(-200vh);
}

.resetXRTL{
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.resetXLTR{
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly rather than writing all that code to check if the element is in the viewport, you'd be better served using an IntersectionObserver (much less painful). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

```js
const animateElementRTL = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.animateRTL'));
const animateElementLTR = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.animateLTR'));


const animateOnEntry = (entries, observer) => {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    if (entry.intersectionRatio === 0) {
      // completely out of viewport, stop animation
      if (entry.target.classList.contains('animateRTL')) {
        entry.target.classList.remove('resetXRTL');      
      } else {
        entry.target.classList.remove('resetXLTR');
      }
    } else if (entry.intersectionRatio === 1) {
      // fully visible in viewport, start animation
      if (entry.target.classList.contains('animateRTL')) {
        entry.target.classList.add('resetXRTL');      
      } else {
        entry.target.classList.add('resetXLTR');
      }
    }
  });
}


const rtlObservers = animateElementRTL.map((elem) => {
  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(animateOnEntry, {
    root: null,
    rootMargin: "0px",
    threshold: [0, 1]
  });
  observer.observe(elem);
  return observer;
});

const ltrObservers = animateElementLTR.map((elem) => {
  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(animateOnEntry, {
    root: null,
    rootMargin: "0px",
    threshold: [0, 1]
  });
  observer.observe(elem);
  return observer;
});
```

Edit: One approach (there are several) to apply the kind of 'stepped' CSS animation you're seeing involves leveraging the `threshold` array in the `IntersectionObserver` options object, along with the `rootMargin` property in the options object.

For example, you could step the animation based on the percentage of the element that is visible on the screen by doing:

```js
const rtlObservers = animateElementRTL.map((elem) => {
  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(animateOnEntry, {
    root: null,
    rootMargin: "0px",
    threshold: [0, 0.2, 0.5, 0.8, 1]
  });
  observer.observe(elem);
  return observer;
});
```

Which would then cause an intersection event to fire, and you could apply a different CSS class based on the `intersectionRatio` being 0, 0.2, 0.5, 0.8, 1.

You could additionally make this start firing from further in than the viewport edge by apply a root margin (for example, a root margin of `2em, 0, 2em, 0` would result in the intersection thresholds being calculated from 2em (32px) in from the top and bottom of the viewport, rather than the edge of the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer however I still not having the same animation as this website: https://www.viraly.com.br/
They have like a keyframe based on scroll.
The animation that I have is fixed, there's only one animation.

Check this: https://i.imgur.com/ImsImbk.mp4

This is your code fixed:

```
const animateElementRTL = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.animateRTL'));
    const animateElementLTR = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.animateLTR'));

    const animateOnEntry = (entries, observer) => {
      entries.forEach((entry) => {
        if (entry.intersectionRatio === 0) {
          // completely out of viewport, stop animation
          if (entry.target.classList.contains('animateRTL')) {
            entry.target.classList.remove('resetXRTL');
          }

          if (entry.target.classList.contains('animateLTR')) {
            entry.target.classList.remove('resetXLTR');
          }
        } else {
          // fully visible in viewport, start animation
          if (entry.target.classList.contains('animateRTL')) {
            entry.target.classList.add('resetXRTL');
          }

          if (entry.target.classList.contains('animateLTR')) {
            entry.target.classList.add('resetXLTR');
          }
        }
      });
    }

    const rtlObservers = animateElementRTL.map((elem) => {
      const observer = new IntersectionObserver(animateOnEntry, {
        root: null,
        rootMargin: "0px",
        threshold: [0, 1]
      });
      observer.observe(elem);
      return observer;
    });

    const ltrObservers = animateElementLTR.map((elem) => {
      const observer = new IntersectionObserver(animateOnEntry, {
        root: null,
        rootMargin: "0px",
        threshold: [0, 1]
      });
      observer.observe(elem);
      return observer;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Hi Gustavo, you can leverage the solution I provided to apply this kind of approach. I'll edit my solution to describe how you can do it.